# unable to render jquery mobile styles in phonegap + backbone app

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I Have developed an app in phonegap using backbone, require js.
jquery mobile js are loaded from the main js.

As per my knowledge, require js will load all js for me. so i dont have to load them manually using `<script>` in my `index.html`

What am i not looking to? Is there a specific method to load the jqm in phonegap + backbone
I have loaded the jqueryMobile library here.

```
require.config( {
  paths: {
        "jquery": "libs/jquery",
        "jquerymobile": "libs/jquerymobile",
        "underscore": "libs/lodash",
        "backbone": "libs/backbone"
  },
  shim: {

        "backbone": {
              "deps": [ "underscore", "jquery" ],
              "exports": "Backbone"  //attaches "Backbone" to the window object
        }
  }} );
require([ "jquery", "backbone", "routers/mobileRouter" ], function( $, Backbone, Mobile ) {
$( document ).on( "mobileinit",
    function() {
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    }
)
require( [ "jquerymobile" ], function() {
    this.router = new Mobile();
}); } );
```

This is my index.html `head`. since i am loading my mobile js initially, i dont need the jqm script for the styles in my header.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<title>RideSmart App</title>
<script src="js/libs/require.js" data-main="js/mobile"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm1.3.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jsLib/phonegap.js"></script>  
</head>
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to trigger a `'create'` event on your page after Backbone has rendered it, as suggested in the "Enhancing new markup" section of the documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html).

> However, if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via
>   Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to
>   handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within
>   the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page
>   div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin
>   (listview button, select, etc.).

```
$( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );
```

If you're using [Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette) you can override the `onRender` hook it provides to do this automatically. Something like this:

```
// Override Marionette onRender and onShow events so JQM 'create' event is
// triggered on view's element. This ensures dynamically created content
// is given the jQuery Mobile treatment
Marionette.View.prototype.onRender = Marionette.View.prototype.onShow = function() {
  this.$el.trigger('create');
  return this;
};
```